# Datanucleus JDODetachedFieldAccessException when adding new field

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int oldField;
}
```

which has the following meta-data file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdo xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdo http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdo_2_0.xsd">
  <package name="my.package">
    <class name="MyClass" detachable="true">
      <inheritance strategy="new-table"/>
      <field name="oldField" null-value="exception"/>
    </class>
  </package>
</jdo>
```

When I add a new field, `private int newField`, and add the corresponding meta-data entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdo xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdo http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdo_2_0.xsd">
  <package name="my.package">
    <class name="MyClass" detachable="true">
      <inheritance strategy="new-table"/>
      <field name="oldField" null-value="exception"/>
      <field name="newField"/>
    </class>
  </package>
</jdo>
```

I get this exception when trying to get the value of `oldField` field:

```
javax.jdo.JDODetachedFieldAccessException: You have just attempted to access field "oldField" yet this field was not detached when you detached the object. Either dont access this field, or detach it when detaching the object.
```

which isn't thrown if I delete `newField`. Adding `default-fetch-group="true"` to `newField` tag in the meta-data file doesn't solve the issue.

The persistence code is as follows:

```
public MyClass addMyClass(MyClass myClass)
{
    getPM().makePersistent(myClass);
    return getPM().detachCopy(myClass);
}
```

Comment: you don't post any persistence code here, so nobody can see _where_ you are accessing things, when attached and when detached, and how you are detaching objects

Comment: The log says the exception mentioned above.

Comment: yes, but i'm sure it says lots of other things, like what it is loading, and the SQL to load